# Is it possible to use derived methods like findById when working with tarantool without lua scripts?

Tags: spring-boot, tarantool, crud-repository

Is it possible to use derived methods like findById when working with tarantool without lua scripts? Just

```
 EntityTarantool findById(int id)
```